# Getting error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0,

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Hello everyone I am getting some error on my website when i upload it on server. It gives me this error on line number 29

**Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Source Error:**

```
Line 27:     <compilation debug="true">
Line 28:       <assemblies>
Line 29:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 30:         <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
Line 31:       </assemblies>
```

Please tell me why it is happening

Comment: Does your server support .Net 4?

Comment: Is the .net framework 4.0 installed on the target server and the AppPool for the sites to 4.0 integrated ?

Comment: @Miller yes .net framework is installed on the server and this application is also developed in 4.0

Comment: go to the assembly (GAC ) and see if you have dll or not on the server

Comment: I mean Application Pool for the site is chosen 4.0 framework integrated in the Site Setting in the IIS

Comment: i dnt have access to iis so is there any other way to do so @Miller

Comment: How do you deployed then?

Answer (score 0):

Set Copy Local to True on your `System.Web.Routing` reference, that means it'll be pulled across as part of your deployment.